# Can I trace a spoofed text message?

Tags: authentication

Someone is texting me threats and I have no idea who. Is there a way to "unspoof" the number? I know for a fact that they are spoofing as a legit number, because I called it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your cell phone carrier will likely have the capability to do this for you. However for privacy reasons (silly I know) they may be reluctant to share the source number with you. However you may be able to ask them to permanently block that number from contacting you.

In addition if what is being sent to you possibly violates the law, of course you should contact your local law enforcement.

Comment: I do appreciate the response. I dont know wat the 9 18 means, but I sure wish I could validate my suspiscions. Thats wat i kinda figured. I have a computer repair shop and have customers asking these type questions quite often. I will refer them to this board/forum and enjoy looking around myself. Concerned parent here. Anyway, thanks for the answers and Have a Great Day